# Displaying multiple labels of point using QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, clustering, multiple

I work with a stitch layer under QGIS. For each point, a variable containing 4 labels.
Using point group symbology, I can display the value of a cluster for a label. To display the 4 values, I need to duplicate the layer but when a point contains several labels, they overlap.

How do I display for each point the values ​​of each label?

The picture below illustrates my point.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now I have found a solution with QGIS: I duplicated my layer (4 layers because 4 variables). I chose a symbology 'group of points' and by clicking on the symbol of the cluster we can shift the symbol displayed from the centroid with x and y. cf capture ps.: my goal was to count the number of apartments, outbuildings, etc. for a given plot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use rule based labeling

[image]